# Negation and Entailment for Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> If Γ ⊨ ψ, then Γ ⊭ ¬ψ.

> If Γ ⊭ ¬ψ, then Γ ⊨ ψ.

I created these two sets of sentences, where Γ is a set of sentences and ψ is a sentence. I believe the first is true but the second is false by thinking about it like this: "If it's raining, then my car is wet. Thus, if it's raining, it's not automatically true that my car is not wet." For the second sentence, "If it's raining, then it's not automatically true that my car is not wet. Thus, "If it's raining, my car is wet."

However, I'm not sure if my semantics are correct.

Comment: What are the specific values of $Gamma$ and $\psi$ in question here? Is $\Gamma$ a particular structure or a set of sentences?

Comment: @MarkSaving Γ is a set of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Both implications can fail.

For the first example, take $\Gamma = \{\bot\}$, and let $\psi$ be any sentence you like. Then $\Gamma \models \psi$ and $\Gamma \models \neg \psi$. The first property holds iff $\Gamma$ is consistent.

For the second, take $\Gamma = \emptyset$ and $\psi = P$. Then $\Gamma$ doesn’t model $\psi$ or $\neg \psi$. The second property holds iff $\Gamma$ is complete.

Comment: When you say "iff $\Gamma$ is complete", what do you mean by that? "Complete" has quite a few different meanings in logic.  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic))

Comment: @NicolinoWill Syntactical completeness